# How to show label in pie chart using chart js?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, chart.js, pie-chart

I have a simple section in which I am showing data from the database using php and ajax,

Here is data I am getting from database

```
 console.log(data); 

[{"selectedcountries":"All available countries","country":"5"}]
```

Here is how I am displaying in pie chart using chartjs

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "xxxx",
      success:function(data)  {
            console.log(data);
            var country = parseInt(data[0].country);
            var ctx = document.getElementById("countryPiechart").getContext('2d');
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'pie',
                data: {                 
                      labels: ["country"],
                      datasets: [{
                        label: 'Genders',
                        data: [country],
                        backgroundColor: [
                          "#4b77a9"
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                    options:{
                    tooltips: {
                    enabled: false
                      },
                      plugins: {
                    datalabels: {
                        formatter: (value, ctx) => {                        
                          let sum = 0;
                          let dataArr = ctx.chart.data.datasets[0].data;
                          dataArr.map(data => {
                              sum += data;
                          });
                          let percentage = (value*100 / sum).toFixed(2)+"%";
                          return percentage;
                        },
                        color: '#fff',
                      }
                  }
              }
          });                  
        }
    });
})
```

The above solution gives me this

[image]

But I want this

[image]

What do I need to change to get what I want?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to show this message as title?

Comment: I mean something like this here https://emn178.github.io/chartjs-plugin-labels/samples/demo/ look the first pie